# lxd: error: remote images exists as <https://images.linuxcontainers.org:8443>

Tags: 15.04, lxc, lxd

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 desktop version. I have installed lxd successfully on my machine. Unfortunately while trying to add remote images i get following error message.

```
$ lxc remote add images images.linuxcontainers.org
error: remote images exists as https://images.linuxcontainers.org:8443
```

What does it signify. I searched web for this issue but could not find any proper answer. Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Strange!! Images were already configured. Ran sudo lxc remote list command and there they were.   +---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+ | NAME | URL | PUBLIC | +---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+ | images | images.linuxcontainers.org:8443 | YES | | local | unix:// | NO | | lxc-org | images.linuxcontainers.org:8443 | YES | +---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+ –

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this with 15.10 on my laptop and then verified it with a 14.04 system also.

It seems that the remote images are loaded already. So, the error being returned by 'lxc remote add images images.linuxcontainers.org' means that its in the 'remote list' already. This is possibly an extra step that does not have to be done. A user just has to go straight to 'lxc image list images:' and then list 'lxc remote list'.